# How can I link my Bootstrap buttons to php code that receives data from client

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap, I need to connect each bootstrap button to a certain value that is received by server from a client using (GET request).

Values are receives by server and stored in mysql database to be displayed later in the bootstrap webpage that contains buttons for each value.

What is the easiest way to do so?

I will attach the php code that receives the value (Steinhart) and store it in the database.

```
  <?php

   include("connect.php");

   $link=Connection();


      $timeStamp="";
      $result="";
       $query="";

      $Steinhart = isset($_GET['Steinhart']) ? $_GET['Steinhart'] : '';

      date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dubai");
      $timeStamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());


     $query= "INSERT INTO `time` (`id`, `timeStamp`, `Steinhart`) VALUES  (NULL, '$timeStamp','$Steinhart')";


     mysqli_query($link, $query);
     mysqli_close($link);

        header("Location: ../indexx.php");
      ?>
```

Bootstrap code for the button:

```
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">

                                    <i class="fa fa-fire fa-3x "></i> 

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div>Ambient Temperature</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Its a little bit vague question. Do you want to fetch data using ajax ?

Comment: yes, when I click on my button I need it to open another link and show me the value of my GET request

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery with Ajax to send request to your php code like:

make you button like this:

```
<button id="mybutton" data-steinhart="your insert data">Do!</button>
```

make your jQuery code

```
$("#mybutton").Click(function(){
    var data = $(this).data('steinhart');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'yourphpfile.php',
        data: {
            'data': data
        },
        success: function (data) {  
            console.log(data);              
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What should I put instead of ("your insert data") ?

Comment: I changed my button to the one that you put, and I added the jQuery code inside <script> </script> in the same html file that has the button but it didn't work. What should I put instead of ("your insert data") ?

Comment: you will put the data your want to insert it to database. I fix the code please recopy,